# How to disable the ContextMenu but not the right click event in a WebView

Tags: javascript, java, javafx-8

I have tried with the `setContextMenuEnabled(false)` method of the `WebView` class, but that also disables the right click event an does not pass it to the website, so no javascript events can be triggered.

I found other answer that shows how to add more options to the context menu, thing that I do not want to do, I just want to disable the contextMenu but no the event.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]? This works fine for me.